# What does 'that of' mean in this example?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

> My other day job is that of the father of two.

What does 'that of' do here? Is it necessary to complete the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of "that of" here might be a "shortening" of

> My other day job is the job of the father of two.

to avoid using the word "job" twice.

However, I find both the above sentence as well as the original sentence a bit clunky. A more natural (US English) phrasing might be

> My other day job is being the father of two.

There is a good discussion of the usage of ["that of"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61711/whats-the-exact-usage-of-that-of) here.